# PHP use global variable

Tags: php, xml, variables, global, xml-parsing

I have some problem with PHP global variable usage. I searched from StackOverflow, but nothing is like mine (at least i didn't found).

I have 2 php page. **Index.php and Account.php**. Index.php calls account.php by ajax. Account.php must receive some xml data from other URL and store it. After that Index.php must use it.

**on index.php:**

```
$("#login-submit").click(function(){
          $("#span-login-loading").css('visibility','visible');
          var dataString = 'user='+ $("#login-name").val() + '&pass=' + $("#login-pass").val();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pages/account.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
              $("#login-form").html(data);
              $("#span-login-loading").css('visibility','hidden');
              if (data.substr(0, 12) == "Logged in as"){
                $("#div-login-submit").html('<a href="pages/account.php?logout=1" id="logout">Гарах</a>');
              }
            }
          });
          return false;
        });
```

**on account.php:**

```
$xml_data = "<loginRequest>
        <username>" . $_POST['user'] . "</username>
        <password>" . $_POST['pass'] . "</password>
      </loginRequest>";
    $url = "url here";

    $username = "name here";
    $password = "pass here";
    $process = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
    $return = curl_exec($process);
    $info = curl_getinfo($process);

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($return);
    curl_close($process);
```

How can I pass $xml into index.php ? My question is more like "How can I store xml type object in session". Because currently I using session for store data. But in case of string data its working okey with below line:

```
$_SESSION['user_name'] = (string)$xml->request->username;
```

If I remove (string) from it, it made error like  **Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0**, But I need pass object, not string.

Comment: Could you rewrite your second paragraph? Are there 3 pages or 2? user.php, index.php, account.php. Also which page is php.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($return);
echo $xml; // add this line at the end of account.php
curl_close($process);
```

Additionally - when you want to get contents of $xml from within other php pages, you can populate a variable by getting the processed page of accounts.php like this

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://yourserver.com/pages/account.php');
```

And to convert contents to xml object:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://yourserver.com/pages/account.php'));
```

Comment: I will use this $xml in other parts in index.ph and also in other pages, not only in place which ajax returned.

Comment: Right now, I'm doing with your example. But how can I use $xml now? I tried `echo $xml->result`, but it says `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`.

Comment: Also `file_get_contents` getting all my codes inside page. Not printed contents.

Comment: use full path of server, not local path to file and get file contents will get printed contents

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution should pass through serialization: you can save your xml object into session like this:

```
$_SESSION['whatever']=$xml->asXML();
```

and retrieve it as

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($_SESSION['wathever']);
```

**NOTE:**
serialization is an improper use of the term, as simplexml does not implements the serializable interface, as far I can see from the docs, and thus we have to *serialize* it
relying on the functions simplexml provides